# How to solve pager display in the in JQgrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, pager

the pager show the add, edit button and all but the no of rows per page option only not show properly. how to solve this.

[image]

here i mark it problem. I set full of width and i set default , but i am not get the full view of pager view, so any help me to come out this problem.

**Updated**
After add the CSS code i got the jqgrid like this

[image]

Comment: put some code so we can look into this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to add the following CSS rules

```js
.ui-jqgrid table { border-collapse: separate; }
.ui-jqgrid .ui-pg-input, .ui-jqgrid .ui-pg-selbox { width: auto }
```

I would recommend you to add `height: "auto"` [option](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aoptions).

Comment: thanks @Oleg, but the Number of row per page dropdownlist box should not be show fully, i updated the image after add the your css code. Please check the image and give the solution.

Comment: @KumarShanmugam: You are welcome! I'm not shure what you want. The CSS selector of dropdown is `.ui-jqgrid .ui-pg-selbox`. So you can add setting for  `font-size`, `line-height`, `height`, `margin` or any other in the CSS rule `.ui-jqgrid .ui-pg-selbox { /*here*/ }`. Your current code contains changing of default CSS styles to the pager element. For example `height: auto` is always good, but it would be good specify other settings to improve the look of pager elements. You should just specify more exact rule which will overwrite the settings.

Comment: hi i have one small doubt about the jqgrid... after select the row in the grid, to click the edit icon in navgrid to show the value in the myPHP_form ? is it possible or not? Please help me....

Comment: @KumarShanmugam: Sorry, but I don't understand what you mean. Do you included `editable: true` property in the columns which you allows to edit in the form?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46999/discussion-between-kumar-shanmugam-and-oleg)

Comment: its ok Oleg... but please consider my question when you have to time and reply to me.... i hope you.. thanks see you later...

Comment: @KumarShanmugam: You can create any your custom form, but you should do it **yourself**. It's unclear what should be so different in the form. The advantage of usage **standard** functionality: you can use *small* code to do the job. It's enough typically just to use some minimal customization of the form which jqGrid creates. By the way I prefer in the most cases to use [inline editing](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing) instead of [form editing](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing). By clicking (or double click) one edit the data.