# jqgrid pager losing good style when inserting into a new website

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, joomla, jqgrid

I had built a custom component with the jqGrid package in a Joomla 1.6 site a few years ago.  I am migrating to a new Joomla 3.3 site.  What is happening is that the pager of the grid has lost some of the styling.  The old site looks like this:
[image]

and the new site looks like this:
[image]

You can see the pager on the second one is messed up.  The scripts are a little dated, but I have them saved on the server and they the files are identical on the 2 sites:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="/CSS/custom-theme/jquery-ui-1.8.15.custom.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="/CSS/ui.jqgrid.css" />

<script src="/JavaScript/jquery-1.7.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/JavaScript/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/JavaScript/i18n/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/JavaScript/jquery.jqGrid.src.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/JavaScript/jquery.timepicker.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

So I am thinking it must be some problem with the new Joomla site's CSS.  Just hoping someone might have some ideas how to trouble-shoot the problem.

I had tried this fix: http://aleemkhan.wordpress.com/2014/05/05/fix-jqgrid-pager-input-too-wide/, and it seems like the right direction but doesn't quite clean everything up.  Since the styling works correctly on the old site I would love just to identify what is over-writing or canceling the styling that I want, but I am not sure how to find it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's well known problem (see [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21605082/315935) for example). jqGrid specifies the CSS rules on the pager or the select box not exactly enough. So *some other CSS rules* could be applied to the pager elements and changes the style of it.

To solve the problem I suggest you to include some additional CSS rule on your page. I suggest that you use `.ui-jqgrid .ui-pg-table .ui-pg-input` to specify pager input style and `.ui-jqgrid .ui-pg-table .ui-pg-selbox` for the select. For example you can try the following

```
.ui-jqgrid .ui-pg-table .ui-pg-input, .ui-jqgrid .ui-pg-table .ui-pg-selbox {
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    line-height: inherit;
    padding: 1px;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 11px;
    margin: 1px;
}
```

Comment: once again Oleg is the highest jqGrid master of all time!  Thanks so much!

Comment: @jeffery_the_wind: I'm glad that I could help you. You are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, run your scripts outside of Joomla to make sure it isn't a problem with your javascript (not copying all the code over, for example).

If it works outside Joomla, then I'd start by installing Firebug for Firefox.  You can use this to inspect the css on individual page elements.  This will allow you to both compare what styles have changed on the pager and where those styles are set.  This should show up if any of Joomla's styles are overriding yours.

Finally, save the page as html and delete the Joomla aspects one-at-a-time until it starts working. For example, if you delete a link to your template's style sheet and it starts working, then the problem is most likely to be found there.

Comment: Very nice, sometimes it just takes hearing someone else's routine.  I will give it a try.